# Hawtio Logs tab is not appearing in Hawtio 2.14.4

Tags: java, apache-camel, log4j, log4j2, hawtio

I'm not able to see **Logs tab** in `Hawtio 2.14.4`. We are using Hawtio to monitor Camel routes and message exchanges. Hawtio's `hawtio-log` plugin/dependency used to provide `Log4jLogQuery` class which we used to configure as spring bean as below and was responsible to copy Camel logs into Hawtio.

```
<bean class="io.hawt.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery" destroy-method="stop"
        id="logQuery" init-method="start" lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"/>
```

This class is deprecated and removed from Hawtio 2.14.1 onwards. I'm not sure what needs to be done so that Logs tab starts appearing in Hawtio and log monitoring is enabled.

We are using:

- Hawtio 2.14.4
- Camel 3.11.2
- AdoptOpenJDK 11
- Tomcat 8.5.20